ASP.net core 5.0 Razor Page redirection to new IP
I am working on a Asp.net core 5.0 webserver based on Razor Pages.
The website hosts a configuration page where the user can change the current server IP, that is the address of the server where the application is running.
In other words, the chain of events is this one:

Server wakes up, start hosting on IP 1
User visit IP1/configuration page and does their configuration
Such configuration causes a change from the server IP from IP1 to IP2
in this case I would like to redirect the user to the new page.

In order to achieve this, I use this code:
if (address != this.Address)
    return RedirectPermanent($@"http://{this.Address}/configuration");

This is where I got stuck: the pages stays there, non responding (since the ip is changed)
and not redirecting.
When I run the debug I get this log:
[15:20:33.254 DBG] [(C:\Projects\Vabw\RI636\SERVER\Pages\Configuration.cshtml.cs) OnPostAsync, Line 493] Previous address: 172.18.1.101 GUI address: 172.18.102.134 CFG address: 172.18.102.134
[15:20:33.299 INF] Executed handler method OnPostAsync, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult.
[15:20:33.303 VRB] Page Filter: Before executing OnPageHandlerExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.HandleOptionsRequestsPageFilter.
[15:20:33.307 VRB] Page Filter: After executing OnPageHandlerExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.HandleOptionsRequestsPageFilter.
[15:20:33.311 VRB] Page Filter: After executing OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.PageHandlerPageFilter.
[15:20:33.313 VRB] Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
[15:20:33.316 VRB] Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
[15:20:33.319 VRB] Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult.
[15:20:33.338 INF] Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to http://172.18.102.134/configuration.
[15:20:33.341 VRB] After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectResult.
[15:20:33.343 VRB] Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
[15:20:33.348 VRB] Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
[15:20:33.349 VRB] Resource Filter: Before executing OnResourceExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
[15:20:33.353 VRB] Resource Filter: After executing OnResourceExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.
[15:20:33.356 INF] Executed page /Configuration in 5971.6781ms
[15:20:33.359 INF] Executed endpoint '/Configuration'
[15:20:33.368 DBG] Connection id "0HN3DPSOMK7JP" completed keep alive response.
[15:20:33.376 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://172.18.1.101/configuration/80085 application/x-www-form-urlencoded 601 - 301 0 - 6099.0317ms

To me it looks like the redirect call went through, but then the original post call supercedes and prevents the redirect action to happen..?

you will be having CORS issues you you will need to add necessary CORS headers in the app. this will make the app suspectible to XSS attacks which you should keep in mind.

can you inspect DevTools network tab to see what's happening on the browser? what is the HTTP code of the redirection? is it 301 or 308?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301 recommends using 308 instead of 301 for specifically POST requests, because apparently some browsers turn POST requests into GET requests when performing 301 redirection. for GET requests, 301 is good.

Thank you for your answers, but I think the issue is that the app address (that is the server IP) changes before the post call is completed, therefore everything is not valid anymore.
Probably the best solution would be to show a popup, but once again the server is now on a different place. My issue is that I currently have no way to get the new address without actually changing it...

Pls bear with me asking a question here, I want to know whether we could visit http://{IP2}/configuration in a new tab of the same browser after changing the IP1 to IP2?

If I understand the question, that/s exactly what I want to achieve. Ideally I wanted to open the new address in the same tab, but if it is necessary to open a new one than it's fine.

I solved my issue without using redirect at all.
The problem lied in the fact that, during the execution of the OnPost call, the IP server would change unbeknownst to the client. then any redirect would originate from a completely new origin, with the effect of the client standing still.
So instead of actively redirecting the client to the new IP, I simply saved the current configuration, and in case of an IP change I would revert to the old one, render the page with a message telling the user to go to the new address. In the meantime a Task.Run(() => UpdateIp()) routine will update the ip to the new one adter an empirically set delay of 2.5 secs.
In conclusion, the answer to my original question is "It is NOT possible because the connection refers to a non existing server", but I managed to find a workaround that lets users get to the new page.
